# Pivot or similiar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 5 countries that all have been assigned with a risk score.
I want to bring the vertically displayed countries & risk scores to display horizontally with the risk scores assigned to the respective countries but fail to do the pivot right.

I tried a pivot :

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
p.[QandA Key],p.[Form Submission Date],p.[FSP Number],p.[Answer],p.[AML_Risk_Score] 
FROM [dbo].[v_QandA_AMLRiskScore] p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[v_QandA_AMLRiskScore] c
on p.[QandA Key] = c.[QandA Key]
WHERE p.[Question Code] in ('AMLCFTQ0260','AMLCFTQ0261','AMLCFTQ0262','AMLCFTQ0263','AMLCFTQ0264')
) t
PIVOT(
SUM([AML_Risk_Score] )
FOR [Answer] 
in( 
 [Country 1]
,[Country 2]
,[Country 3]
,[Country 4]
,[Country 5]
)
)
AS pivot_table`
```

This one does not provide the riskscores, as they are all NULL.
[image]

Then I tried this, with differnt effect but not successfull either:

```sql
SELECT 
[FSP Number],[Form Submission Date]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0260'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END AS [Country1_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0261'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END AS [Country2_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0262'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END AS [Country3_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0263'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END AS [Country4_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0264'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END AS [Country5_Risk]
FROM [dbo].[v_QandA_AMLRiskScore]
WHERE [Question Code] in ('AMLCFTQ0260','AMLCFTQ0261','AMLCFTQ0262','AMLCFTQ0263','AMLCFTQ0264')
```

This results in this:
[image]

what it should look like is:

[image]

How does the code need to look like?

@siggemannen Now I tried this:

```
SELECT 
[FSP Number],[Form Submission Date]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0260'THEN SUM([AML_Risk_Score])  END AS [Country1_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0261'THEN SUM([AML_Risk_Score])  END AS [Country2_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0262'THEN SUM([AML_Risk_Score])  END AS [Country3_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0263'THEN SUM([AML_Risk_Score])  END AS [Country4_Risk]
,CASE WHEN [Question Code]='AMLCFTQ0264'THEN SUM([AML_Risk_Score])  END AS [Country5_Risk]
FROM [dbo].[v_QandA_AMLRiskScore]
WHERE [Question Code] in ('AMLCFTQ0260','AMLCFTQ0261','AMLCFTQ0262','AMLCFTQ0263','AMLCFTQ0264') 
and [FSP Number] = 'FSP7442' and [Form Submission Date]= '2021-07-01'
group by [FSP Number],[Form Submission Date],[Question Code]
```

But still get this:

[image]

How do I bring it down to one line?

Comment: Your second looks good, you just need to actually do a group by and SUM your case whens

Comment: @siggemannen, thank you, But cannot get it working. I edited my txt above to show what I tried. Thank you

Comment: Answered you separately

Comment: Put the case expressions inside SUM().

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work better:

```sql
SELECT 
    [FSP Number], [Form Submission Date]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'AMLCFTQ0260'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END) AS [Country1_Risk]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'AMLCFTQ0261'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END) AS [Country2_Risk]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'AMLCFTQ0262'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END) AS [Country3_Risk]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'AMLCFTQ0263'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END) AS [Country4_Risk]
    , SUM(CASE WHEN [Question Code] = 'AMLCFTQ0264'THEN [AML_Risk_Score] END) AS [Country5_Risk]
FROM [dbo].[v_QandA_AMLRiskScore]
WHERE [Question Code] IN ('AMLCFTQ0260', 'AMLCFTQ0261', 'AMLCFTQ0262', 'AMLCFTQ0263', 'AMLCFTQ0264') 
AND [FSP Number] = 'FSP7442' AND [Form Submission Date] = '2021-07-01'
GROUP BY [FSP Number], [Form Submission Date]
```